# How can a prop value be used in an Stitches js component?

Tags: css, reactjs, stitches

How to pass a prop value into a Stitchesjs component and use it in the component definition?

This is a common pattern in `styled-components`. In Stitches, however, I can't seem to find a way. Take this component for example:

```
const Spacer = styled('div', {
    '16': {marginBottom: '$16'},

    variants: {
        size: {
            '20': {marginBottom: '$20'}
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of creating 10 variants, I want to pass the amount trough a prop:

```
<Spacer size={'30px'} />
```

or even better:

```
<Spacer size={'$sizes$3'} />
```

How can I use this value so that the `marginBottom` matches whatever I give it?

Comment: As far I understand that is a limitation of the design, since it has almost no runtime, it cannot interpolate props on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://stitches.dev/docs/utils.

And then you can use like this:

```
<div css={{ mb: '$40' }} />
```

Answer (score 6):

There was a discussion on Stitches Github about the possibility to pass dynamic values as property.
But the goal of stitches is to have the smallest `runTime` possible, so it was not implemented !

[Github PR stitches](https://github.com/modulz/stitches/pull/721)

When you need to use a JSX variable in stitches that can be any value, one solution would be to use CSS variables;

All stitches elements get the `css` property, and you can pass new properties through it!

**Styled component:**

```
    export const Box = styled('div', {
    marginTop: 'var(--margin-top)',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    })
```

**Component:**

```
export function Hero({props = 200 }) {

  const variableExample = `${props}px`
  return (
    <>
    <Box css={{ '--margin-top': '10px' }} />
    <Box css={{ '--margin-top': '150px' }} />
    <Box css={{ '--margin-top': variableExample }} />
    </>
  )
}
```

By far the best solution that has worked for me for this very problem. simplifies the code and is better to maintain later!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this answer and tried a few different ways.

The easiest way for me turned out to be [locally scoped theme-tokens](https://stitches.dev/docs/tokens#locally-scoped-tokens).

So your styled component would look like this:

```
const Spacer = styled('div', {
    marginBottom: '$$marginSize',
});
```

And then pass the locally scoped token into the `css` prop:

```
<Spacer css={{ $$marginSize: '$sizes$3' }} />
```

Comment: This works, but will create one single custom css variable, if you give spacer a new prop via css, it will re-write the old value